# Geocoding sensitive addresses without API

Tags: geocoding, open-source-gis, privacy

I have a large set of sensitive addresses that I need to Geocode on a server.  I cannot send them to an external API due to HIPAA restrictions.  Ideally I'd love to use an open source solution, even if it is not perfect.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 3):

[SmartyStreets](https://smartystreets.com) provides an address validation service that returns all kinds of data about addresses, including geocodes. While most people use the external API hosted by SmartyStreets, they do offer [Enterprise](https://smartystreets.com/pricing/enterprise) customers the option of hosting it themselves.

The service itself is not open source, but the [SDKs](https://smartystreets.com/docs/sdk) are. (Disclosure: I am a software developer at SmartyStreets)

Comment: I see the enterprise option is $5000/mo which is more than we can afford.  Do you think it would be possible to negotiate a lower price for a one-off conversion of addresses to geocodes?

Comment: @Selah - It would be worth asking. As a developer, that is not my area of expertise, but here is the URL of the SmartyStreets contact page: https://smartystreets.com/contact

Answer (score 0):

[YAddress](https://www.yaddress.net) offers geocoding tools that you deploy locally on your network, and no data ever leaves your premises. (I work for the company.)